# Mobile Scrolling Not Working On Nested Divs

Tags: css, mobile, scroll

I have a scrollbar on my **body**.
But I am not able to scroll the body when I try to scroll from a **div** contained into another **div**

```
    <body> //scrollable
      <div> //can scroll the body
        <div> //can not scroll the body
        </div>
      </div>
   </body>
```

Is anyone know why?

Comment: Either put your html/css code or create a JSfiddle of your problem, it is near to impossible to understand your problem what you have posted so far :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it by using this library: http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe

```
    //scrolling issue
    $("#myDiv").swipe( {
        //Generic swipe handler for all directions
        swipeStatus:function(event, phase, direction, distance, duration, fingers) {
            var curY = window.scrollY;
            if(direction == "up") window.scrollTo(0, curY + 10);
            if(direction == "down") window.scrollTo(0, curY - 10)
        },
        swipeUp:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
            window.scrollTo(0, distance);
        },
        swipeDown: function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
            window.scrollTo(0, window.scrollY - distance);
        },
        threshold: 10,
        cancelThreshold: 10
    });
```

Comment: Actually your question is not up to the mark and your answer also doesn't properly answer to your question...:)